# Angular $http service call in for loop and use of closure in for loop

Tags: javascript, angular

In Following code i always print 3

```
   var deleteDocuments = function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           service.deleteDocument().then(function(res) {
               $log.debug("i=",i);

           });
       }
   };
```

service.deleteDocument() is a simple $http call service.
I have to use closure function here .

What is correct optimize way to write closure in above condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closure typically (and basically) is a function written inside a function. For the task you're doing I don't think you can 'optimize' a closure because you need to perform that action. Here's an example of a closure for you.

```
var deleteDocuments = function(src) {
       for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           closure(i);
       }

       function closure(i){
            //  Do something
          service.deleteDocument().then(function(res) {
               if (!$scope.isEKYC && $scope.uploadedDocument[i]) { 
               }
           });
       }
   };
```